# What does Android Location hasBearing check?

Tags: android, location

I'd like to check if a bearing is available on a location, and, if so, use it. This is basically what I'm doing:

```
if (loc.hasBearing()) {
    // code that uses bearing
} else {
    // log no bearing
}
```

The code in the if block gets executed for lots of locations with a bearing of 0 (Math.floor'd), and 0 wasn't the actual bearing.

I do try to make sure I get bearings (or at least that I use a provider that supports bearing):

```
criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
criteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
```

I am putting the location into an intent's extras and taking it out again... maybe that has something to do with it? I'm just using putExtra and getParcelable - I wouldn't think that would corrupt the locations.

I'm thinking of just ignoring bearings of 0.0, which shouldn't have too many false positives, but I was hoping there was a clean use of the API for me instead.

Comment: Ignoring bearings of 0.0 doesn't have false positives since 0.0 is not part of the range of valid bearings `(0.0, 360.0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing()):

> Get the bearing, in degrees.
>
> Bearing is the horizontal direction of travel of this device, and is
>   not related to the device orientation. It is guaranteed to be in the
>   range (0.0, 360.0] if the device has a bearing.
>
> **If this location does not have a bearing then 0.0 is returned**.

Since `getBearing()` returns 0.0 if the location has no bearing you can safly ignore it.

Comment: Thank you - I was hung up on hasBearing returning false positives, and I didn't read the getBearing doc... the excluded 0.0 in the doc solves my problem even if it doesn't answer my question about why hasBearing appears broken.